# Explicit bounds for counting integer points inside $2$-norm balls

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometry-of-numbers

It is well known that a ball of $2$ norm radius $R$ in $d$ dimensional space constains
\begin{align}
    N(R) = V_d R^d + \mathcal{O}(R^{d-2})
\end{align}
points with integer coordinates (i.e. elements of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ embedded in $R^d$ in the obvious way), as long as $d\geq 4$. Here $V_d$ is the volume of the $d$ dimensional unit ball. I believe this result follows from the $4$ square theorem. My question is can we obtain bounds of the form
\begin{align}
   \left\lvert{N(R) - V_d R^d}\right\rvert \leq a_d R^{d-2}.
\end{align}
or, if this is too difficult, something like
\begin{align}
   b_d R^d \leq N(R) \leq c_d R^d, 
\end{align}
for some reasonable $a_d$ and $b_d$ and $c_d$?